# Bootstrap navigation button isn't working on mobile version

Tags: html, css

I tried to make an responsive bootstrap navigation bar but something isn't working. I even copy/paste the bootstrap navbar example and still the button doesn't show the menu when I click on it.

Can you help me solve it ?

```
        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg cust">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand pSize" href="#">
                        <img src="log.png" class="d-inline-block imgBrandSize">
                        Logo
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand pSize" href="#">
                <img src="log.png" class="d-inline-block imgBrandSize">
                Logo
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

this is working properly. This is `Bootstrap-5`. Please use `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` insted of `data-toggle` and `data-target`

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This Code

- I hed Two changes in your code.
  This Is **Bootstrap v4.0.0**

  ```
   <div class="header">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
       <div class="container">
           <a class="navbar-brand pSize" href="#">
               <img src="log.png" class="d-inline-block imgBrandSize">
               Logo
           </a>
           <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
               data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Text</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </nav>
  ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udFw1.png)